# How do I prevent javascript from converting my dates to GMT?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a timestamp given by

```
timestamp = 2015-02-22T10:00:00.000Z
```

Why is it converted to GMT when I do this

```
var dt = new Date(timestamp);
console.log('dt = ' + dt); // prints Sun Feb 22 2015 05:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

I don't want it to convert my date to GMT. How do I prevent javascript from converting my dates?

Comment: So do you just want it to be printed in UTC? The Z at the end is code for Zulu, eg UTC timezone. Also, the 2 datetimes are equivalent, 2015-02-22T10:00:00.000Z is the same instant as Sun Feb 22 2015 05:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to execute `dt = ' + dt`, Javascript tries to convert the `dt` object to a string so it can be added to another string.  It does that by calling the `dt.toString()` method and the format you are seeing is the default string conversion for a date object.

FYI, this default format that looks like this:

```
Fri Mar 06 2015 19:24:42 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

is NOT GMT time.  The time value shown is local time.  It is showing you that local time shown is -0800 hours from GMT, but the time itself is expressed in local time.

It's not uncommon to want to just truncate off the last part of this and display:

```
Fri Mar 06 2015 19:24:42
```

That can be done like this:

```
console.log('dt = ' + dt.toString().replace(/\sGMT.*$/, ""));
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hg5m0r1r/

---

If you want something different to show, then you should construct the string representation you want yourself rather than letting the system automatically call `.toString()`.  You can look at the Date object methods available and decide what you want to display.  A Date object internally is a number of ms since the epoch time so any string representation is a conversion of some kind.  You have to tell it what conversion you want.

You can see a list of the many date methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).